# Pokémon GO Egg Hatching Distances

Tags: pokemon-go

According to [Incubators and hatching Pokémon Eggs](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049967-Incubators-and-hatching-Pok%C3%A9mon-Eggs-):

> Each Egg displays the number of kilometers you must walk for the Egg to hatch. In general, the more kilometers required, the rarer the Pokémon that will hatch. A notification will appear when the Egg has hatched.

What are the common distances? I just found my first egg and it requires 5 km to hatch. I'm curious as to how rare that is.

Bonus Questions:

- How rare is it to get an egg from PokéStops?
- What Pokémon can you get from eggs?

Comment: The second bonus question is well covered below. For the first, I've found it quite common to get new eggs from PokéStops shortly after previous eggs hatch. As a data point, I've hatched 123 so far, have four more currently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eggs come in three distances: 2km (1.2mi), 5km (3.1mi), and 10km (6.2mi). The distribution of these seems to be relatively random, however 5km seems to be somewhat more common than the others. 10km seems to be somewhat rarer for now, however these numbers have become extremely balanced since the beta.

Pokemon's strength (and rarity) is usually determined by the distance you need to walk to hatch the Egg.

You can get any non-legendary (and egg-grouped Pokemon) from eggs, although some are rarer than others. For instance, you're much more likely to get a Rattata than a Growlithe from an egg.

Comment: How does the app qualify the walking? Does the app need to be open and the device unlocked for it to register?

Comment: @DavidYell yes. You can turn on Battery Saver and hold the phone upside down to black out the screen, but the app must still be running.

Comment: I've heard that there are also 20km eggs, but I have yet to see one with my own eyes.

Comment: I have not seen any of those 7km eggs yet, and haven't heard of them from anywhere else. That seems incorrect.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

**2 kilometre eggs**

Bulbasaur
Charmander
Squirtle
Caterpie
Weedle
Pidgey
Rattata
Spearow
Pikachu
Clefairy
Jigglypuff
Zubat
Geodude
Magikarp

**5 kilometre eggs**

Ekans
Sandshrew
Nidoran♀
Nidoran♂
Vulpix
Oddish
Paras
Venonat
Diglett
Meowth
Psyduck
Mankey
Growlithe
Poliwag
Abra
Machop
Bellsprout
Tentacool
Ponyta
Slowpoke
Magnemite
Farfetch’d
Doduo
Seel
Grimer
Shellder
Gastly
Drowzee
Krabby
Voltorb
Exeggcute
Cubone
Lickitung
Koffing
Rhyhorn
Tangela
Kangaskhan
Horsea
Goldeen
Staryu
Mr. Mime
Tauros
Porygon

**10 kilometre eggs**

Onix
Hitmonlee
Hitmonchan
Chansey
Scyther
Jynx
Electabuzz
Magmar
Pinsir
Lapras
Eevee
Omanyte
Kabuto
Aerodactyl
Snorlax
Dratini

Comment: And for 10km eggs sometimes you get low CP Onix's three times in a row, but never a Snorlax. *Darn you Random Number Generator!*