# Do Eevees hatch more frequently than other 10k Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have had a total of four 10k eggs that I have hatched. Out of those four, 3 have been Eevees and 1 Scyther.

Now in my, likely shared, opinion Eevee is the worst thing to get from a 10k egg. But in fact (I believe) it IS the most common to find outside the egg. Does that commonness have any relation to how common they appear in my 10k eggs, or do I just have bad breeding luck?

Comment: Although a Snorlax or Lapras would be nice, I wouldn't call Eevee the 'worst'. Eevee is pretty valuable - only 25 candies to evolve, and Vaporean particularly can be quite strong.

Comment: @TimMalone Very true but worst in the sense that I can get an eevee walking down the street any given day but finding a wild Lapras not so much. A good Vaporeon is very strong but I already have tons of them.

Comment: I've hatched 4 10k eggs...no eevees

Comment: @Evorlor I dislike you...:p

Comment: Personally, I would say the worst 10k is Jynx, it's more common and more useless than Eevee's. But I would say you are just unlucky to get 3 of the same 10k's out of 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well although there's no official information about this, at least as far as I know, there's been some tests on [TheSilphRoad on Reddit](https://reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vrocr/egg_hatch_probability_distributions/) and therefore all credits go to them, more specially [vector010](https://reddit.com/user/vector010) as he's made the post.

Users have been asked which Pokémon have hatched from which egg, and [this](https://netherfable.com/pgo-egg-hatch-distribution/) is the result.

Here is the part about the Pokémon from 10km eggs only:

[image]

You'll see that Eevee actually seems to be more common than the other Pokémon. Obviously it might also just be random, but I, personally, think this information is valuable enough to make statments such as *Eevee has a higher spawnrate from eggs than others*.

Comment: Perfect this is the kind of answer I was looking for, although a small sample it is good data and seems to follow what I've seen that the more common in the wild (around me at least) are more common in eggs. I do find it strange though that regional is included are they not 5k eggs?

Comment: Yes, about the regional Pokémon seem to be some different informations about, at [this site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272604/pok%C3%A9mon-go-egg-hatching-distances) you'll find all the regionals marked at the 5km egg, whereas on the [egg distribution] (https://netherfable.com/pgo-egg-hatch-distribution/) of TheSilphRoad **Mr. Mime is marked as a hatchable from 10km**. So I guess we don't know yet.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that it is somewhat random, although it could be based on location somewhat...... I have hatched 6 Scyther, 4 Pinsir, 4 Onix, 1 Eevee, as well as a few other singles but no Snorlax (although I have caught 6), Lapras, or Jynx.... and I have run into countless Scythers and Pinsirs. They are everywhere where I live.

Comment: This is mostly based on opinion...

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. I hatched 5 10 km eggs out of which I got 3 evees and 2 scythers. I think both of them are common.

Comment: This does not definitively answer the question. It provides evidence, but does not say 'Yes' or 'No'.